# Why can't I upload a large file over https?

Tags: python, c, ssl, gevent

I'm attempting to upload a large file over https using geventhttpclient.

I'm getting a traceback that includes:
string longer than 2147483647 bytes

That's 0x7fffffff BTW - the highest number you can store in a 32 bit signed integer.

Hunting around for "string longer than.*bytes", I see it's in _ssl.c .

It's a little odd though - I'm on a 64 bit Linux Mint 17.3 - I'd think the limit would be 2^63-1 instead of 2^31-1.

The relevant part of _ssl.c appears to be:

```
  if (buf.len > INT_MAX) {
      PyErr_Format(PyExc_OverflowError,
                   "string longer than %d bytes", INT_MAX);
      goto error;
  }
```

I wrote a little test program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Size of int is %lu\n", sizeof(int));
        fprintf(stderr, "Size of size_t is %lu\n", sizeof(size_t));
        fprintf(stderr, "Size of ssize_t is %lu\n", sizeof(ssize_t));
        fprintf(stderr, "Size of void * is %lu\n", sizeof(void *));
        fprintf(stderr, "Size of long is %lu\n", sizeof(long));
        fprintf(stderr, "INT_MAX is %u\n", INT_MAX);
        fprintf(stderr, "size of Py_ssize_t is %lu\n", sizeof(Py_ssize_t));
        return 0;
        }
```

Which gives output of:

```
Size of int is 4
Size of size_t is 8
Size of ssize_t is 8
Size of void * is 8
Size of long is 8
INT_MAX is 2147483647
size of Py_ssize_t is 8
```

So it seems like my INT_MAX is little (32 bit), even though my Py_ssize_t is big (64 bit).

However:

```
$ /usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python
cmd output started 2016 Tue Aug 30 08:41:43 AM PDT
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jun 14 2016, 10:45:41)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```

What do I need to do to get INT_MAX up to 2^63-1 ?

I'm aware that I can upload a file in chunks using a generator (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests), but I'd rather just upload in one go if practical.

I compiled this Python myself with --enable-shared and a $LDFLAGS.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: my ISP limits upload speeds to about 1 MBit/sec on a domestic account. This is to inhibit such accounts being used for hosting servers. So even the `2147483647` size file would take nearly 5 hours to upload even if continuous transmission.

Comment: You can't. The INT_MAX is a define for a maximum value the `C` `int` type variable may hold. The gcc (and most other `C` compilers) define the `int` as 4-byte integer. You need to re-implement that _ssl.c in a way it uses `long int` instead of `int`. But then you may get in trouble with http server that could be not capable to accept message bodies longer than 2^31-1 bytes

Comment: I just noticed that buf.len is being cast to int for the benefit of SSL_write, which I presume is part of the SSL library.  So perhaps this would mean modifying libssl.so.1.0.0.  Oh well.

Comment: Gcc ints are usually 4 bytes long, no surprise, this is compiler/platform dependent. Two languages, two different types, no surprise. What surprise me is that (it seems) you tried to write more than 2^32 bytes in a single operation? Is that it? Do smaller writes in a loop (not hard to design) if it is possible or push smaller chunks (not hard to design).